# Is there a package management system for python that supports inheriting from USER.SITE?

Tags: pip, anaconda, virtualenv, pipenv, python-poetry

I work with Deep Learning libraries like PyTorch, transformers etc. And it is time-taking and therefore an overhead to install these heavy libraries separately in every virtual environment. Nor do I want to mess up with the system site-packages location. Shouldn't there be a solution to this where we can inherit the user site-packages from virtual environments? Shouldn't virtualenv support this?

I've tried using virtualenv with the option --user-site, as suggested by Google Bard, but it didn't work. Also checked out tools like pipenv, conda but couldn't find much help there too. Or am I missing something?

Comment: inheriting site-packages is - in my opinion - counterintuitive to the idea of haveing virtual environments. I suggest though that you take a look at conda again. While it is true that you need to `conda instal` libraries in each environment, `conda` downloads packages to a global directory and then links them into the seperate envs. As long as you have the same version in all envs, you will only need the disk space and download time once

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. 
Also, I've just figured out that the --system-site-packages of pip can also access packages installed in USER.SITE, so it effectively also works as --user-site if ever there was such an option.